# Is it possible to add custom data in magento 2 rest API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, integration

I am using rest/all/V1/products/:SKU API for fetching product details. 
Now issue I am facing is that i wanted to add one custom data in this API response.

I wanted to append "SellerID" custom data along with product details which I am getting from API. 
I tried some solutions but not able to add it in the response. 
Can any one help me to append seller id in product response ?

Answer (score 1):

For that purposes Magento proposed the `ExtensionAttributes`. Add your data to the product extension attributes in `etc/extension_attributes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="seller_id" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

write a plugin which add this value to the products data:

```
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface $extension */
    $extension = $item->getExtensionAttributes();
    if ($extension === null) {
        $extension = $this->extensionFactory->create();
    }
    $extension->setSellerId($item->getData('seller_id'));
    $item->setExtensionAttributes($extension);
```

and you can see your data in the response in `extension_attributes` section of the product.

Comment: I stored extension attribute using Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCreationArgumentsInterface in sales_shipment table but now I need to get that shipment extension data using shipmentId. so I tried Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface after get method for add that extension data but i faced issue. so please help me. see my detailed question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/359113/93504